# Postgres regular expression strip leading zeo

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am working on a regular expression to remove leading 0 from a Highway number. so far I have

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('S SR 0060 HW','0?','','g'))
```

This removes the 0 after 6 in addition to removing the leading 0s and makes the output as `S SR 6 HW`. The desired output should be `S SR 60 HW`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('S SR 0060 HW',' 0+',' ','g'))
```

Comment: or `Select trim(regexp_replace('S SR 0060 HW',' 0*',' ','g'))`

Comment: Both solutions work. Thank you so much vks and Avinash

Answer (score 3):

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('S SR 0060 HW',' 0+',' ','g'))
```

You can try this.

or

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('S SR 0060 HW','\m0+',' ','g'))
```

`\m` matches start of word.